# Magento 2 How to create admin form through UI Component

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I want to build a **simple magento 2 backend form**.

**What is the most appropriate way to do this?**

> With form UI Component or with a phtml template.

**The form just make some action** and **NOT saving data to database.**
`No CRUD operations, NO Data Entities...` Just some controller actions when submit form.

Comment: Since you are creating form in backend, so UI Component is the standard way to do it.

Comment: check this link: https://webkul.com/blog/create-ui-form-magento2-part-1/

Comment: Ok but as I wrote there is no data source. No crud operations

Comment: In above link you can skip **DataProvider.php** file if you don't want CRUD.

Comment: not working as you said... 
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class vvvvv\sssss\Model\DataProvider does not exist

Comment: Have a similar requirement, did you ever find an answer to this?